# Does $\left| \int_a^b f dx \right| \le C$ for all $a$ and $b$ imply $f \in L^1(\mathbb{R}; dx)$?

Tags: real-analysis, improper-integrals, lebesgue-integral

Let $f : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ be Borel measurable such that there exists a $C > 0$ so that for all $-\infty < a < b < \infty$,
$$\left| \int_a^b f dx \right| \le C,$$
where  $dx$ denotes Lebesgue measure.

> I would like to know whether $f \in L^1(\mathbb{R}; dx)$.

For instance if $g \in C^1(\mathbb{R}; \mathbb{R})$ with $\sup|g| < \infty$, then by the fundamental theorem of calculus $|\int_a^b g' dx| \le 2\sup|g|$ for all $a,b$. I would like to conclude that $g' \in L^1(\mathbb{R};dx)$.

I am not able to prove the above assertion nor can I think of a counterexample. Fatou's lemma yields
$$\int_{\mathbb{R}} |f|dx \le \liminf_{n \to \infty} \int_{-n}^n |f|dx,$$
but under the given hypotheses I'm not sure how to show the right side is bounded. Since $|\int_{a}^b f dx| \le C$ for *any* $(a,b)$, maybe I can say something separately about the positive a negative parts of $f$?

Hints or solutions are greatly appreciated.

Comment: What about $f(x) = \sin(x)$?

Answer (score 1):

This is false. If $f$  is a continuous function with an improper Riemann integral from $-\infty$ to $+\infty$ then hypothesis holds but $g$ may not be integrable w.r.t Lebesgue measure.  A standard example is $f(x)=\frac {\sin x} x, x \neq 0, (f(0)=1)$.